# PHP/CSS can't get element to sit over a table?

Tags: php, css, html

I have a div relatedListings that contains a table of customer's orders.

I want to add a heading above it, I have tried h3, div, and span but it always puts the element below the table.

The code that generates the table:

```
echo '<div id="relatedListings">
        <h3 id="relatedListingsHeader">Customer\'s Listings</h3>' .
        $account->listAds() .
    '</div>';
```

The actual source from the browser after executed:

```
<table id='customerAds'>
    <!-- Generated table data -->
</table><div id="relatedListings">
        <h3 id="relatedListingsHeader">Customer's Listings</h3></div>
```

Notice in the second snippet, the div is AFTER the table.  Any ideas?

EDIT: here is the listAds method:

```
echo "<table id='customerAds'>
                <tr><th>Ad</th><th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Ad Date</th><th>Actions</th></tr>";

        while ($ad = $ads->fetch()) {
            echo "<tr id='row_{$ad['idAds']}'>
                    <td>{$ad['idAds']}</td>
                    <td>{$ad['Title']}</td>
                    <td>" . substr(strip_tags($ad['Description']), 0, 100) . "...</td>
                    <td>" . format::dateConvert($ad['DatePosted'], 12) . "</td>
                    <td><a href='#'>Delete</a></td>
                </tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";
```

Comment: What is listAds() doing? Returning a string or doing more echo's?

Comment: Where is the code the output the table?

Comment: I see that your code snippet does not emit any table tags, so you have not actually posted "code that generates a table"

Comment: ahh i think i got it.. i need to return a string because of how i'm calling the method...  thanks for pointing that out ott

Comment: Hey @guyfromfl, just as a tip you should look into a coding practice that doesn't require you to use php to echo out html. Take a look at some php frameworks (code ignitor, zend, yii, etc) that have your html within "views" and then you render and output those without having to write the html in PHP.

Comment: csjohn, thanks for the input.  The company I am talking about transferring to uses code igniter, so maybe it wouldn't be such a bad idea to start learning lol...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would venture to guess that $account->listAds() is echo-ing as well and not returning instead. If you can change that function to return instead you should be better off.

**Update:**
Now having seen your updated code - I'd suggestion having that function return a string - instead of using echo like you are

```
$tableCode = "<table id='customerAds'>
            <tr><th>Ad</th><th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Ad Date</th><th>Actions</th></tr>";

    while ($ad = $ads->fetch()) {
        $tableCode .= "<tr id='row_{$ad['idAds']}'>
                <td>{$ad['idAds']}</td>
                <td>{$ad['Title']}</td>
                <td>" . substr(strip_tags($ad['Description']), 0, 100) . "...</td>
                <td>" . format::dateConvert($ad['DatePosted'], 12) . "</td>
                <td><a href='#'>Delete</a></td>
            </tr>";
    }

    $tableCode .= "</table>";
return $tableCode;
```

Comment: yup already did it and its working fine...i still have to wait 3 minutes to check this answer...

Answer (score 0):

Your generated table data may be malformed, causing the browser to try and fudge the markup into what it thinks you meant.  Since you didn't include that markup, I couldn't tell for sure.  It would also be helpful to see the code from `$account->listAds()`.